# Convert into const(char)* from float in D

Tags: string, d, char-pointer

DrawText's first argument needs to be a `const(char)*` but i tried using to! for that and have failed :(

```
yVel = to!(string)(player.vel.y);
DrawText(yVel, player.pos.x, player.pos.y - 40, 20, RAYWHITE);
```

How to properly convert from float to `const(char)*` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`to!string` converts from float to string. Then `toStringz` converts from string over to a `const char*`. So just combine them.

Or for more control and efficiency, you could define a little stack buffer and `sprintf` or something as well.

Generally `some_string.ptr` will give something you can use as `const char*`, just make sure you put the 0 terminator at the end before passing it to most C or Windows functions.